# translate point based on the point side attribute and link direction

Tags: postgis, point, address, move

I have address points with house number and their side.
For instance, there is a point of house number 10, and it's side is Left (whether Right or Left)

[image]

I also have the link that has relationship with the point (it shares same link_id)

what I want to do is translate the location to certain distance away from the link.

[image]

I think I probably have to draw perpendicular lines that cross the link at the house address points and move points based on the points side attribute.

I believe the centroid of the perpendicular line is the house address point
the link has from node and to node so I think I can calculate the direction yet I do not know how to find out direction of the link in this type of shape

[image]

I do not know where and how to start :(
What I have found so far is
st_azimuth, st_makeline, st_translate..

Comment: ST_Azimuth to get angle, add 90 degrees, use ST_Translate with the x,y values coming from cos and sin of whatever angle you get from the first part.

Comment: @JohnPowell can i get an azimuth of the link at the house address point? if so, how?